# Pass Application or ApplicationContext to ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-context

I have a small question.
I am working on an Android app and I am using the MVVM design pattern.

I need to pass the Application Context to some of the ViewModels and to the Repository, because of actions like: instantiating the Room Database, playing sound files, saving small data into Shared Preferences. I did that using Dependency Injection.

I know that there is only one instance of the Application Context, so there will be no memory leaks if I pass it, unlike Activity Contexts.

Here comes my unclarity: I found that passing ApplicationContext (Context instance) works, but also does Application (Application instance). What is the difference between these two options? Which one is better to pass as an argument?

Comment: You should not pass the ApplicationContext or Application instance to the ViewModel **directly**. Pass an abstraction to the ViewModel (f.i. ISoundProvider) and the implementation of that will get the ApplicationContext or Application instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application` object *is literally the same object* as the object returned by `getApplicationContext()`.

If you're using an [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) with the default factory, you'll get an `Application` object suitable to use as a `Context` (as `Application` extends `Context`).

Comment: To be fair, I suspect that the OP is being confused by the availability of both `getApplication()` and `getApplicationContext()` on `Activity` (the latter inherited from `Context`). I'm sure that 12+ years ago there was a reason why we wound up with the duplication there... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare - `Activity` extends `Context`, so it inherits `getApplicationContext()` from that. The fact that it returns a `Context` instead of an `Application` is mostly due to the small window of time around backup/restore (which isn't relevant for ViewModels or Activities) where these *are* different. Hence, getting an `Application` object is perhaps more useful in the context of an Activity and the same reason you get an `Application` for `AndroidViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the difference! There may be more to it, as backup/restore wasn't a thing in API Level 1 IIRC. But I had never heard of that scenario for where `getApplicationContext()` *didn't* return the `Application` singleton, so that's good to know!